# Firefox spamming SECCOMP events to journal/syslog - how to fix?

Tags: firefox, selinux, systemd-journald, sandbox

Since I updated to the snap-based Firefox on Ubuntu recently, I see it reporting SECCOMP_RET_TRAP messages to the journal whenever some application is drawing a canvas.

And since applications drawing canvasses usually do that with 30 frames per second,
there is a lot of useless spam filling up the log, and, in fact, also consuming a lot of CPU usage.

What I could dig up was that this sort of behaviour was reported before, but both sides tried to pass the buck, then fell back to a plain "wontfix". ( https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1465152, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1507282, https://linux-audit.redhat.narkive.com/BnWpkAXa/limiting-seccomp-audit-events )

So, **how can one keep the journal from being flooded with** useless "a canvas has been drawn in your browser! Oy vey! Run for help" messages? Is there some configuration where you can filter **specific SECCOMP messages**, or better: **keep Firefox from generating** these?

(addition: sample line
`Sep 13 16:01:48 MYHOST audit[97745]: SECCOMP auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=? pid=97745 comm="CanvasRenderer" exe="/snap/firefox/1775/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=312 compat=0 ip=0x7f48ae38573d code=0x50000`)

Edit: I am not looking to

- turn off security entirely
- stop all security events from getting logged
- recompile applications or kernel

I want to tone down/turn off the spamming by configuration in a reproducible way, so everybody with the same issue can apply that solution.
Dropping messages matching a specific "comm" field value, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until the issue is properly fixed by either Mozilla or Canonical, you can disable audit logs for Firefox as a temporary workaround.

Start by installing `auditd` to allow managing audit logs:

```
sudo apt install auditd
```

Add an audit rule to the end of `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` to exclude logging Firefox:

```
-a never,exclude -F exe=/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

Alternatively, you can create a separate file and add the audit rule there (e.g., `/etc/audit/rules.d/firefox.rules`).

Enable and start the `auditd` service:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now auditd
```

Verify the rule is loaded:

```
sudo auditctl -l
```

Restart the `auditd` service if you ever need to update the rule:

```
sudo systemctl restart auditd
```

Comment: Thank you! suggested improvement: there is an /snap/firefox/current/... directory. Might that remove the need to update the rules? And tidying up: place above filter line as separate file in /etc/audit/rules.d ; the rules get recombined automatically on (restart).

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions. Using `/snap/firefox/current/` does indeed avoid the need to update the rule as it is a symlink that should always point to the directory of the newest version.